# Problems reading an Excel file in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, file-upload, oledbconnection, data-connections

I have been trying to upload and read an Excel file (.xls, or .xlsx)

I am upploading sucessfully using this code:

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles    btnUpload.Click
    Dim filepath As String = ""
    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        Try
            Dim filename As String = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
            Dim extension = (filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf("."), (filename.Length() - filename.LastIndexOf("."))))
            If extension = ".xlsx" Or extension = ".xls" Then
                filepath = "\" & Common.toUnix(Now) & "_" & filename
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") & filepath)
                  ' ====   NOW READ THE FILE
            Else
                StatusLabel.InnerText = "Only Excel file types are accepted (.xls/.xlsx)<br> File Uploaded had extension: " & extension
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            StatusLabel.InnerText = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.ToString()
        End Try

    End If
End Sub
```

It uploads OK, but when trying to read the file I get this error:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.
```

I am using code to read similar to this:

[vb.net traversing an xls / xlsx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989347/vb-net-traversing-an-xls-xlsx-file)

Therefore the connection is as follows:

```
 Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" & _
                           ";Data Source=" & ExcelFile & _
                           ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"

    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = Nothing
    Dim excelDataSet As New DataSet()

    Try

        conn = New OleDbConnection(connString)

        conn.Open()  '<<< ERROR IS RAISED ON THIS LINE
        dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
        If dt Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Dim excelSheets(dt.Rows.Count) As String
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            excelSheets(i) = row("payments").ToString
            System.Math.Min(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i), i - 1)
            If i = SheetNumber Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

     ..................
```

I'm uploading to a shared server so don't have control as to permissions as such, but I do have read/write permissions and uploading Images works OK, but it's reading this file that I can't get to work.

**NOTE**

This error occurs with .xls files, when using .xlsx I get this error:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Cannot update. Database or object is read-only. at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal
```

This error occurs on this line:

```
 For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
```

So it appears it is uplpoading and opening the file OK, but not reading the rows....

I am not sure why that's happening either!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you want to read `xlsx` files, you need to use ACE OLEDB provider. Try this connection string `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=myFile.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;""` For xls files try it with this `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=myFile.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;""`

Comment: OK, tried that and I am geting ` The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine` being a shared server that I don't have control of, I can't do much with this? I can't find a .dll to download, only an EXE file from Microsoft, which I can only install locally.

Answer (score 0):

ACE is brutal, have troubles with it all the time and it cannot exist on a System in both 32 and 64 bit version at the same time. As a result I just dont use it at all.

To read an Excel XLSX file I use "[EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/89923)" which has proven to be very easy to deal with and extreamly efficient.

It ONLY works with XLSX (**not** XLS)

Example... (simple just pulls out first sheet as a datatable)

```
    Public Function XlsxToDataTable(byteStream As IO.MemoryStream) As DataTable
        Using pac As New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(byteStream)
            Dim wb As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook = pac.Workbook
            Dim ws As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet = wb.Worksheets(1) '1 based
            Dim out As New DataTable
            For iC As Integer = 1 To ws.Dimension.End.Column
                out.Columns.Add(ws.Cells(1, iC).Value.ToString)
            Next
            For iR As Integer = 2 To ws.Dimension.End.Row
                Dim nr As DataRow = out.NewRow
                For iC As Integer = 1 To ws.Dimension.End.Column
                    nr(iC - 1) = ws.Cells(iR, iC).Value
                Next
                out.Rows.Add(nr)
            Next
            Return out
        End Using
    End Function
```